# Некорректная отправка сообщений в простом клиент-серверном приложении

Tags: c++, клиент-сервер

Добрый день, столкнулся со следующей проблемой. При отправке сообщения с клиента на сервер происходит следующее: если в введенном сообщении присутствует пробел (например, Hello world) то на сервер оно приходит не одним сообщением, а двумя. То есть отдельно приходит hello, отдельно world. Однако, если я захардкоживаю сообщение (например char message[50] = "Hello world"), то оно отправляется корректно одной строкой. Не могу понять в чем проблема. Прилагаю код. Использовал visual studio 2012.

client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "mswsock.lib")

class client{
public:
    void init();
    void Connect();
    void close();
private:
    void sendMessage();
    char PCName[30], ServerName[30];
    std::string Message, IP; 
    WSAData WSADat; // Свойства WinSock (результат функции WSAStartup)
    sockaddr_in sin; // Свойства(адрес) создаваемого сокета
    SOCKET Sock; // Клиентский сокет
};

#endif //CLIENT_H
```

client.cpp

```
#include "client.h"

void client::close(){
    closesocket(Sock);
    WSACleanup();
}

void client::sendMessage(){
    for(;;){
        std::cout << "Enter message: ";
        std::cin >> Message;
        if(Message.size() < 201){
            const char *message = Message.c_str();
            if (send(Sock, message, strlen(message) + 1, 0) != SOCKET_ERROR){
                std::cout << "Sent!\n";
            }
            else{
                std::cout << "Error of sending!\n";
            }
        }
        else{
            std::cout << "Message is too big \n";
        }
    }
}

void client::Connect(){
    do{
        std::cout << "Enter server's IP: ";
        std::cin >> IP;
    }
    while(IP.size() > 16);
    const char *Ip = client::IP.c_str();
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(Ip); // IP-адрес сервера (пори создании сервера можно 0)
    std::cout << "Connecting to server...\n";
    if (connect(Sock, (sockaddr*)&sin, sizeof(sin)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        std::cout << "Connection error!\n";
        Connect();
    }

    if ((send(Sock, (char *) &PCName, strlen(PCName) + 1, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){  // Отправка имени этого компьютера (клиента)
        perror("SOCKET_ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }

    if ((recv (Sock, (char *) &ServerName, 30, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){ // Получение имени компьютера сервера
        perror("SOCKET_ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Connected to " << ServerName << std::endl;
    sendMessage();
}

void client::init(){

    WSAStartup(0x0202, &WSADat); // Инициализация WinSock
                                 // 0x0202 - версия WinSock. 2.0, 2.2
                                 // WSADat - структура, куда будут занесены рез. инициализации
    gethostname(PCName, 30); // Получение имени текущего ПК
    sin.sin_family = AF_INET; // Тип адреса
    sin.sin_port = htons(2803); // Номер порта сервера
    Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); // Создание сокета
    if(Sock < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

main.cpp

```
  #include "client.h"
    int main() {
        client client;
        client.init();
        client.Connect();
        client.close();
        return 0;
    }
```

server.cpp

```
 #include "server.h"

int server::numClients = 0;

void server::join(std::thread &th){
    th.join();
}

void server::creatingWorkingThreads(){
    for(;;){
        if(numClients < 3){
            threads.push_back(std::thread ([this](){connect();}));
            numClients++;
        }
    }
    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(), std::bind(&server::join, this, std::placeholders::_1));
}

void server::getMessage(){
    for(;;){
        if (recv(Client, Message, 200, 0) != SOCKET_ERROR) { 
            std::cout << "Message from " << ClientName << " : " << Message << std::endl;
        }
        else{
            std::cout  << ClientName << ": " << "has disconnected" << std::endl;
            numClients--;
            break;
        }
    }
}


void server::init(){
    WSAStartup(0x0202,&WSADat); // Инициализация WinSock
                                // 0x0202 - версия WinSock. 
                                // WSADat - структура, куда будут занесены рез. инициализации

    gethostname(PCName, 30); // Получение имени текущего ПК

    sin.sin_family = AF_INET; // Тип адреса
    sin.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;  // IP-адрес сервера (пори создании сервера можно 0)
    sin.sin_port = htons(2803); // Номер порта сервера
    Sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); // Создание сокета
    if(Sock < 0){
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }
    if(bind(Sock, (struct sockaddr *)&sin, sizeof(sin)) < 0) { // Связывание созданного сокета с адресом sin
        perror("bind");
        exit(2);
    }
    // ***** Ожидание клиента
    std::cout << "Wait of client...\n";
    listen(Sock, SOMAXCONN); // Прослушивание сокета сервером (для подключения клиента)
}


void server::connect(){
    Client = accept(Sock, (sockaddr*)&sin, 0);
    if ((recv (Client, (char *) &ClientName, 30, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){ // Получение имени компьютера клиента
        perror("SOCKET_ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((send(Client, (char *) &PCName, strlen(PCName) + 1, 0)) == SOCKET_ERROR){  // Отправка имени этого компьютера (сервера)
        perror("SOCKET_ERROR");
        exit(1);
    }
    std::cout << "Client " << ClientName << " has connected" << std::endl;
    getMessage();
}

void server::close(){
    closesocket(Sock);
    closesocket(Client);
    WSACleanup();
}
```

server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#pragma comment (lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "mswsock.lib")

class server{
public:
    void init();
    void close();
    void creatingWorkingThreads();
private:
    char PCName [30], ClientName[30], Message[200];
    WSAData WSADat; // Свойства WinSock (результат функции WSAStartup)
    sockaddr_in sin; // Свойства(адрес) создаваемого сокета
    SOCKET Sock, Client; // Серверный и клиентский сокеты
    static int numClients;
    void getMessage();
    void connect();
    void join(std::thread &th);
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
};

#endif //SERVER_H
```

main.cpp

```
#include "server.h"

int main() {
    server server;
    server.init();
    server.creatingWorkingThreads();
    server.close();
    return 0;
}
```

[image: то что делает прилагаемый код]
[image: вариант с захардкоженным сообщением]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::cin` считывает строку до первого пробельного символа.
Для считывания строки с пробелами используйте [getline()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Comment: Большое спасибо, теперь все корректно работает. Но появилась еще проблемка, Из этой же оперы, видимо мне катастрофически не хватает понимания в данном вопросе. Ввожу ip, проходит коннект, но прежде чем я могу отправить первое сообщение, сразу после коннекта, клиент сам отправляет пустую строку. 
Код все тот же, но вместо std::cin>>message, использовал, как вы сказали, std::getline(std::cin, Message);